# VSTS externalnugetfeed is either disabled or uninstalled

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package, azure-artifacts

I have two VSTS collections and I'd like to publish NuGet packages to feeds in each collection. I thought I'd be able to accomplish this with the NuGet Publisher task with a feed type of External. When I try to configure the Nuget Server Endpoint I selected External VSTS, entered my PAT, clicked verify connection and it was confirmed. However upon saving my endpoint I noticed the following under the type information:

> Type: The endpoint type extension externalnugetfeed is either disabled or uninstalled which may lead to issues in using this endpoint.

I cannot select the endpoint in my NuGet Publisher task. I looked in the marketplace and I don't see any relevant extensions. I also looked under extensions and don't see any disabled extensions in either collection.

Comment: The issue has been fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same issue in my VSTS, there is the feedback that you can follow. [Cannot use external NuGet service](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/75624/cannot-use-external-nuget-service.html)

Update: The issue has been fixed now.